# How to give permission to open a log file

Tags: linux, rhel8

I am getting this error like

```
        SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from open access on the file /var/log/error.log
```

what to do here? How can I allow access to this file? Any clue?

Comment: SELinux.  You must add the permission on the log file for httpd to access it.  Or turn off SELinux completly.  But this question is out of scope for SO, you should reach out in linux admin sites, after doing some research on SELinux.

Comment: @Nic3500 could you please refer me some Linux admin site's url

Comment: My guess is you dont google much :)  Site like this one, for sysadmin: https://serverfault.com/.  But SELinux documentation abounds.